# Where did the chicken come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hangover

During the photo-montage end credit sequence for the 2009 comedy hit, [The Hangover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hangover), some light is shed on many of the unexplained occurrences that happened during that lost night.

However, I do not recall seeing where the chicken came from, or why they even had a chicken in their suite.

At the risk of answering my own question, I assume it was there to feed the tiger but, seeing as everything else in the film was neatly wrapped up, is there any documented evidence to explain its appearance in the film?

Comment: I am assuming it was not the same place as where the chicken comes from in Family Guy every now and then? :-)

Comment: The answer is obviously, The Egg

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a [**funny article**](http://filmdr.blogspot.com/2009/06/hangover-and-chicken-mystery.html) 
I found, blogged about this mystery, it is revealed in one section that the Chicken is a few things.

**Officially**, in an interview with Ed Helms, he mentions the director, Todd Phillips, reasoning for the chicken, he states that:

> "...Although Todd will tell you, Todd Philips, the director, when I called him on the chicken I was like `What's the deal with the chicken?' He says that we stole the chicken to feed the tiger."

[**(full official interview here)**](http://blog.thephoenix.com/blogs/outsidetheframe/archive/2009/06/01/interview-with-ed-helms-from-quot-the-hangover-quot.aspx)

But Ed Helms goes on a bit of an extreme stating:

> ".. the chicken is a "symbol of chaos," with possible "Bunuel-esque" overtones."

There are also some funny theories you can link off of in that article, but that I will leave to your own device.